# Difference between discriminant analysis and neural network (one layer)

Tags: neural-networks, references, discriminant-analysis

So I am doing some research on this topic and I "hit a wall" with this question.
I managed to find some papers on using DA vs NN on data but i didn't find anything math related. Maybe someone could help me understand the difference between them mathematically?

Also I have a side question: What does a second layer give to a neural network?

Comment: you should be able to find the differences in Elements of Statistical Learning.  But adding (nonlinear) layers allows the model to build nonlinear decision surfaces